# How to change correlation text size in ggpairs()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `ggpairs()` in the `GGally` package. The pairs plot is of four continuous variables, and I gave another column, a factor with 2 levels, to a `colour` argument which worked very nicely, both coloring the points as I expected and (bonus!) in the upper-diagonal part of the plot reporting the correlations by that factor level. My only problem is that the text reporting the correlations is too small.

Can I increase the size of the text reporting correlations in a `ggpairs()` plot?

I tried giving a `cex` argument, it seems to have no effect. I'm already using `size` for yet another variable; it doesn't affect the text.

For a specific example:

```
require(GGally)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
ggpairs(mtcars, columns = c(1, 5), colour = "cyl")
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also specify the correlation text size in the params.
For your example, you could specify a correlation font size of 12 as follows:

```
require(GGally)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
ggpairs(mtcars, columns = c(1, 5), colour = "cyl", params=list(corSize=12))
```

Comment: Somehow `corSize` makes no difference for me but `size` does. So it might be `upper=list(params=list(size=12)))`. I wonder if things have changes over 2 years.

Comment: *at the time of posting this comment* \\
The use of `params` has been deprecated, you will need to use something similar to `upper = list(continuous = wrap("cor", size=12))`

Comment: How about fixing the spacing of each line or correlations when having groups?

Answer (score 34):

For anyone finding their way to this thread in 2017 and beyond, this has changed slightly.

See schloerke's answer here:
https://github.com/ggobi/ggally/issues/31

ie. to change the font size used in the correlations, use the upper parameter to the ggpairs function like so:

```
ggpairs(mtcars, columns = c(1, 5), colour = "cyl",
    upper = list(continuous = wrap("cor", size = 9)))
```

Answer (score 4):

I dont know if this is the most elegant solution, but in `ggpairs` you can change single plots in your plot matrix.
So if you create a correlation plot like so

```
my_cor <- ggally_cor(mtcars, aes_string(x = "mpg", y = "drat", colour = "cyl")
          , corSize = 10)
```

you can insert this plot into your old matrix with

```
old_matrix <- ggpairs(mtcars, columns = c(1, 5), colour = "cyl")
new_matrix <- putPlot(old_matrix, my_cor, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Any idea how efficient this is? Do you pay the processing time of 1 additional plot to do this?